# Prometheus query to only include sum of labels with other metric value over some value

Tags: prometheus

I'm trying to write a query for calculating the total provisioned memory for VMs on our ESXi hosts out of the total available memory. I only want to include the provisioned memory for active/powered on VMs. I have 3 basic metrics that I would like to combine if possible to get this data.

- `vmware_host_memory_max`
- `vmware_vm_memory_max`
- `vmware_vm_power_state`

If I use this query `sum by (host_name) (vmware_vm_memory_max) / sum by (host_name) (vmware_host_memory_max)` it looks like I have way over provisioned because there are quite a few VMs that are off but are still included in the total of `vmware_vm_memory_max` for a given ESXi host. I'd like to have Prometheus ignore any vm that has a `vmware_vm_power_state` of `0` as it's powered off an not actually using any resources. Or another way of saying that would be to only include a vm if it has a `vmware_vm_power_state` of `1`.

The metrics are coming from the exporter here: [pryorda/vmware_exporter](https://github.com/pryorda/vmware_exporter)

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found the solution... although I'm not sure. The following query appears to give me the sum of all the provisioned memory for VMs that are powered on divided by the total amount of memory available on the ESXi host they are running on.

```
sum by (host_name) (vmware_vm_memory_max and (vmware_vm_power_state == 1)) / sum by (host_name) (vmware_host_memory_max) * 100
```

If this is wrong or there's a better solution, please let me know!